# Select count(*) from multiple tables to create view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, count

How can I select count(*) from two different tables to create view?

There are the tables:

DEPT table

- DEPTNO
- DNAME
- LOC

EMP  table

- EMPNO
- ENAME
- JOB
- MGR
- HIREDATE
- SAL
- COMM
- DEPTNO

I've tried:

```
CREATE VIEW PLACE
AS SELECT d.Loc CITY, count(d.Deptno) N_DEPT, count(e.Empno) N_EMP
   FROM Dept d, Emp e
   where d.Deptno = e.Deptno
   GROUP BY d.Loc, d.deptno;
```

and got this:

```
CITY          N_DEPT   N_EMP
CHICAGO         6       6
DALLAS          5       5
NEW YORK        3       3
```

There is only 1 N_DEPT in each city so the result is wrong :/.
There should be:

```
CITY          N_DEPT   N_EMP
CHICAGO         1       6
DALLAS          1       5
NEW YORK        1       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `DISTINCT`, try

```
CREATE VIEW PLACE
AS 
SELECT  d.Loc CITY, 
        count(DISTINCT d.Deptno) N_DEPT, 
        count(e.Empno) N_EMP
FROM    Dept d 
        INNER JOIN Emp e
           ON d.Deptno = e.Deptno
GROUP BY d.Loc
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :). I was confused by lectures that 'distinct' is forbidden for 'view' :/ but it depends on DB i see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You may also simply count the stuff you want per city without joining the tables to be counted:

```
create view PLACE
as
select d.Loc as CITY,
       (select count(distinct deptNo) from dept x where x.DeptNo = d.Deptno) as N_DEPT
       (select count(distinct Empno)  from Emp  e where e.DeptNo = d.Deptno) as N_EMP
from Dept d
```

This is not ment to be a better solution. It just shows a different way to look at the problem and create a solution. 
What I like about it is that you could add whatever you want to count in the same manner, i.e. it introduces kind of a template.

Comment: It's interesting and clever solution but I got a Message-Log ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row :/

Comment: Sorry, there is a stupid error in my query. It should read `(select count(distinct ...)`. Thanks for showing me the error. I updated my proposal.